# Collect checkbox values in jQuery and POST them on submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, codeigniter

I've referred to this post:

[Post array of multiple checkbox values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557273/jquery-post-array-of-multiple-checkbox-values-to-php)

And this jQuery forum post:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checkbox-names-aggregate-as-array-in-a-hidden-input-value

---

I am trying to collect an array (or concatenated string with commas, whatever) of checkbox values in a hidden input field using jQuery. Here's the script code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function() {
 var form = this;
 $(form).find("input[name=specialty]").val(function() {
  return $("input:checkbox",form).map(function() {
   return $(this).attr("name");
  }).get().join();
 });
});
</script>
```

A snippet of the relevant HTML:

```
<form id="advancedSearchForm" name="advancedSearchForm" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('/magcm/advancedSearch#results'); ?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="FCM" id="FCM" class="chk" value="FCM" <?php echo set_checkbox('FCM', 'FCM'); ?>/>
<input type="hidden" name="specialty" id="specialty" value="" />
<input class="button" name="submit3" id="submit3" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

I've tried changing "submit" to "submit3" in the jQuery, which breaks (obviously). When I print_r($_POST), the checkboxes POST correctly but the condensed hidden variable does not. (It posts, but a blank value.) The checkboxes persist correctly using CI's hacked set_value() function (Derek needs to implement this in the main trunk... but that's another story)

I'm sure I'm doing something that is wrong and easy to point out. I've just been banging my head against the wall for the past 2 hours on it, trying various functions and changing a ton of things and analyzing it in Chrome dev tools (which don't show any errors).

Help is appreciated. :)

Comment: "advancedSearchForm" should be "#advancedSearchForm" to correctly select an ID'd element.

Comment: Whoops, that's a typo in the code here. Fixed. It's actually like that in the view and it is still broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it using PHP arrays rather than jQuery:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="RET" class="chk" value="RET" <?php echo set_checkbox('chk', 'RET'); ?>/>
```

I changed the name to an array and POSTed it to my script, where I looped through the array and handled it there. Still not sure what the problem was with the jQuery-based solutions, but I figured I'd post this for everyone to refer to in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you applied an class, maybe "tehAwesomeCheckboxen" to every checkbox. Then

```
<script>

$("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function() {

     var chkbxValues = $(".tehAwesomeCheckboxen").val();
     $("#specialty").val( chkbxValues.join(",") );

});

</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I don't think the $_POST array is getting populated, since the submit is being handled locally by the JavaScript engine. SO... let's try this:

```
<script>
    var chkbxValues = new Array();

    $(".tehAwesomeCheckboxen").live("change", function(e){
        var val = $(this).val();

        if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
            if( chkbxValues.length == 0 || chkbxValues.indexOf(val) == -1){
                // Add the value 
                chkbxValues.push(val);
            }
        }
        else {
            // remove the value
            chkbxValues.splice( chkbxValues.indexOf(val), 1 );
        }

        $("#specialty").val( chkbxValues.join(",") );
    });

</script>
```

This adds an event handler the checkboxes themselves, such that checking/unchecking the box alters the hidden element. Then your form handles its submission as normal.

Is this more in line with what you're trying to do?

**P.S.** Those who upvoted this, please note I have modified my answer. Please verify whether you still find it useful and adjust your vote accordingly.

Comment: Just FYI, you need to use something to look at the generated source to see if this is doing anything. The Chrome Dev Tools only shows the DOM as the server generated it. Web Developer Toolbar for Chrome or Firefox both have this option.

Comment: I am print_r()'ing $_POST. If the data is POSTed, I'll see it. I have WDT for Chrome and it doesn't show anything either.

Comment: Can I ask what your goal for this piece of code is? Are you trying to build an aggregate value to pass to a PHP handler?

Comment: Yes. I just need all the values of a group of checkboxes sent back. Asynchronous calls are not necessary (nor desired). I just need a single input to collect all the names of the checkboxes selected and POSTed back to a controller.

Comment: Didn't get to this until today, but the modified code doesn't seem to work. In the PHP script, I print_r($_POST) and get this:

`Array ( [location] => [radiusSelect] => 10 [FCM] => FCM [PROV] => PROV [STU] => STU [specialty] => [submit3] => Search )`

PROV, FCM, STU are checkbox values, and specialty is the hidden value.

Answer (score 0):

You've got lots of nested functions() in your JavaScript, makes it hard to follow what you're doing.

However, it seems that you're just passing a function to .val() rather than an actual value.  Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function() {
 var form = this;
 $(form).find("input[name=specialty]").val((function() {
  return $("input:checkbox",form).map(function() {
   return $(this).attr("name");
  }).get().join();
 })());
});
</script>
```

Or even better, calculate the value first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function() {
 var form = this;
 var value = $("input:checkbox",form).map(function() {
   return $(this).attr("name");
 }).get().join();
 $(form).find("input[name=specialty]").val(value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your second example with advancedSearchForm and #advancedSearchForm with no luck. Specialty was not being POSTed.

Comment: Did the first one work? I also hadn't realized that you forgot the hash in the $().