# Getting the values of checked checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the value of all or some of the checked checkboxes and send to PHP using jQuery and AJAX. This is the PHP code that creates the table:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox'></td>";
echo "<td>{$studentid}</td>";
// add the record id here, it is used for editing and deleting products
echo "<div class='studentid display-none'>{$studentid}</div>";
echo "</tr>";
}

//end table
echo "</table>";
```

jquery code to select all the check box

```
$(document).on('click', '.chkbox', function(){ 
    if (this.checked == true) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    }
    else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

$('#delete-students').click(function(){
    // send data to php through ajax method $.post
});
```

I want when this button is clicked I should be ale to get all the id of the student and send to php using `$.post` in AJAX

Comment: use value in checkbox property

Comment: Your checkbox does not have  class="chkbox "

Comment: `chkbox` i can't see this elemnt and `tr` should not hold anyother element instead of `td`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collect checkbox values in jQuery and POST them on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904758/collect-checkbox-values-in-jquery-and-post-them-on-submit)

Comment: This is the class that get all the checkbox selected when clicked           `echo "<th><input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'></th>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,use the arr in your ajax post

```
   var arr = [];

   $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(i, e) {

    arr.push(cFId);

   });
```