# Passing an integer array to an MVC controller via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having some problems passing an integer array to an MVC controller.

I'm grabbing my values as follows:

```
$checkedItems = $(':checked');
```

My ajax post is formatted like this:

```
$.ajax({
              url: '/Items/MarkUnsuitable',
              type: 'POST',
              traditional: true, 
              data: { checkedRecords: $checkedItems, deletionReason: reason, deletionDescription: description },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert('An error occured when processing this request:\r\n\r\n' + thrownError);
              },
```

My controller is receiving the data like this.  The only missing value is the int[]

```
public ActionResult MarkUnsuitable(int[] checkedRecords, int? deletionReason, string deletionDescription)
```

Could anybody assist me with this problem?

Comment: Try using FireBug and see as what data is being sent. Ensure that the data is in format that can be mapped into int[] array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you used Firebug to inspect the data that's being posted yet? If not, that would help. My suspicion is that you don't have a "value" attribute on the checkboxes so you're just posting names with no value.

You might want to build an array manually using `.each`

Check this similar question: [Post array of multiple checkbox values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557273/jquery-post-array-of-multiple-checkbox-values-to-php)

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. var checkedItems = $('*[id*=lead]:checked').map(function (i, n) {
                    return $(n).val();
                }).get();